# Criterion for Affine Scheme via Glueing

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme. Futhermore we denote for a global section $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$  the non vanishing set

$$X_s := \{x \in X | s_x \neq 0 \}$$

(remark: $s_x$ is the image of $s$ under the canonical map $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/m_x =k(x)$ <- (residue field of the stalk at $x$)

My question is how to show that if we know that there exist a ***finite number*** of global sections $t_i \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ such that

- 1) $X_{t_i}$ are open affine
- 2) $X = \cup_i X_{t_i}$, so $X_{t_i}$ cover $X$
- 3) the $t_i$ (by assumption finitely many) generate the global sections ring $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$

Then $X$ is affine!

I tried to show following:

Denote $R := \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $R_i := \Gamma(X_{t_i},\mathcal{O}_X)$

I have two problems:

Firstly, to show that $R_{t_i}= \Gamma(X_{t_i},\mathcal{O}_X) = R_i$ (here $R_{t_i}$ is the localization of $R$ wrt $t_i$). How to verify it?

Secondly: after hoving shown 1) a would like to glue these isomorphisms $R_{t_i} \to  \Gamma(X_{t_i},\mathcal{O}_X)$ to an iso $R \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Locally, on $X_{t_i}$,  the induced morphisms $X_{t_i} \to Spec(R_{t_i}$ between specs are by 1)  isomorphisms of schemes. Does here already a glueing argument work. How concretely?

I often read that for similar local constructions one uses such "glueing arguments" but here on this example I would be glad to see this glueing concretely "in action" to become a better intuition when it works and when not.

Comment: Do you have sources for what you are trying to prove ? If $\mathcal{L}_x$ really mean the stalk at $x$, then $X_s$ is a closed subset of $X$ which is probably not what you are expecting. But if $\mathcal{L}_x$ is the fiber, then the result is obviously wrong (take $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ and $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}(1)$). This result reminds of a lemma but it was stated only for $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}_X$ and with a finite number of $t_i$ only (the result is also wrong if there is an infinite number of them). Is this the result you are looking for ?

Comment: yes you are right, I meant not the stalk $\mathcal{L}_x$ but the residual field $k(x)=\mathcal{L}_x/m_x$ at $x$. Sorry for ambiguous formulation. I want also consider a finite number of the $t_i$ and it seems that you have correct lemma in mind but here I intend to generalize it for arbitrary invertible sheaf $L$ under assumption that conditions 1 and 2 as above hold

Comment: The result is false for an arbitrary invertible sheaf. Look at the counter-example in my previous comment. You might want to put additional assumpion on $\mathcal{L}$, but I don't know them.

Comment: @Roland: hmmm what about if we additionally assume that the $t_i$ (after modification finitely many) generate the global sections ring $\Gamma(X, L)$ as module. I'm not sure if this condition suffice to follow the statement but $L=\mathcal{O}(1)$ don't fulfill that since in this case the $t_i$ ony generate the ideal $(t_1,...t_n)$ of $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(1))= k[t_1,...,t_n]$. So let us assume this condition additionally

Comment: @Roland: For the sake of simplicity how would you argue in case $\mathcal{L}= \mathcal{O}_X$ + conditions 1),2),3)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{L})$ is not a ring, just a module. Then $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(1))$ is the set of homogeneous polynomial of degree 1 (not of every degree) and clearly $t_0,t_2,...,t_n$ span $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(1))$ as a module.

Comment: @Roland: yes I confound some objects. What I meant was that $A:= k[t_0, t_1,...,t_n]$ is a graded algebra with $A_1= \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}(1))$ in case of $X = \mathbb{P}^n$. I seems that the construction only could work for structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$. Above you mentioned a lemma. Was does it say?

Comment: I have in mind the exercise II.2.17(b) in Hartshorne : A scheme $X$ is affine iff there exist a finite set of elements $f_1,...,f_n\in A=\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ such that the open sets $X_{f_i}$ are affine and $f_1,...,f_n$ generate the unit ideal in $A$.

Comment: @Roland: Yes that is it. He indeed starts with iso $X_{t_i}= Spec(R_i)$ and obviously there exist canonical morphism $f: Spec(R) \to X$ given by $id_R$ on the level of rings. Futhermore - as a scheme morphism- $f$ induces $f^{\#}_i: \Gamma(X_{t_i},\mathcal{O}_X) = R_i \to R_{t_i}= \Gamma(D(t_i),\mathcal{O}_{SpecR})$. In 2.16 there is a hint why $f^{\#}_i$ are isomorphisms. I don't really understand it. Could you explain how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This argument comes from Vakil's notes, specifically the proof of the Qcqs lemma. This is lemma 7.3.5 in the [November 18th, 2017 version](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) of his notes.

Use the sheaf property.

We have exactness of 
$$\newcommand\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}0\to \Gamma(X,\newcommand\calO{\mathcal{O}}\calO_X)\to \prod_i \Gamma(X_i,\calO_X)\to \prod_{\{i,j\}} \Gamma(X_{ij},\calO_X),$$
where $X_{ij}=X_i\cap X_j = (X_i)_{t_j}$. Now let $R_i=\Gamma(X_i,\calO_X)$, and note that $X_{ij}=\Spec R_{ij}$ is affine, where $R_{ij}:=\Gamma(X_{ij},\calO_X)=(R_i)_{t_j}=(R_j)_{t_i}$, since $X_i$ is affine. 
Now for any $s\in \Gamma(X,\calO_X)$, localize this sequence at $s$. Since localization is exact, this preserves exactness. Also use the fact that the products are finite, so that we have that localization distributes over them. Thus we have
$$0\to \Gamma(X,\calO_X)_s \to \prod_i (R_i)_s \to \prod_{\{i,j\}} (R_{ij})_s.$$
Note that $X_s = \bigcup_i (X_i)_s$, and the $X_i$s and $X_{ij}$s are affine, so we also have exactness of
$$0\to \Gamma(X_s,\calO_X) \to \prod_i (R_i)_s \to \prod_{\{i,j\}} (R_{ij})_s,$$ 
and we have natural maps downwards from the first sequence to the second. Since the second and third maps are isomorphisms, the first is as well. Applying this to $s=t_i$, we have the desired isomorphisms, $R_i\simeq R_{t_i}$.

Thus you have shown that locally on the target, the natural map $X\to \Spec R$ is an isomorphism, and thus $X\to \Spec R$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Currently, I try to prove the same statement. I wonder how you define the "natural map $X\rightarrow Spec(R)$ in the first place, since the lemma from Vakil's notes only gives isomorphisms $R_i\rightarrow R_{t_i}$ or $X_{t_i}\rightarrow Spec(R)$.